# How can I implement array in this example

Tags: c, arrays, arguments, parameter-passing

I am trying to implement array for buttons, instead of declaring

```
GtkWidget *button1;
GtkWidget *button2;
```

In case I have even more buttons. Here is my code and it runs with no errors. I am not sure how to implement array because for each button I also need a new label name...and add another piece of data here `g_signal_connect`...
Here is my code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

 /* Our new improved callback.  The data passed to this function
    * is printed to stdout. */
   static void callback (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
  {
  system ((gchar *) data);
  }


/* another callback */
static gboolean delete_event (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{
gtk_main_quit ();
return FALSE;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
/* GtkWidget is the storage type for widgets */
GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *button1;
GtkWidget *button2;
GtkWidget *box1;

/* This is called in all GTK applications. Arguments are parsed
 * from the command line and are returned to the application. */
gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

/* Create a new window */
window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

/* This is a new call, which just sets the title of our
 * new window to "My Assignments" */
gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "My Assignments");

/* Here we just set a handler for delete_event that immediately
 * exits GTK. */
g_signal_connect (window, "delete-event",
                  G_CALLBACK (delete_event), NULL);

/* Sets the border width of the window. */
gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 50);

/* We create a box to pack widgets into.  This is described in detail
 * in the "packing" section. The box is not really visible, it
 * is just used as a tool to arrange widgets. */
box1 = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE,0);

/* Put the box into the main window. */
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), box1);

/*creating 1st button*/

button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Run program1");

g_signal_connect (button1, "clicked",
                  G_CALLBACK (callback), "program1");

gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box1), button1, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

gtk_widget_show(button1);
/*creating 2nd button*/

button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Run program2");

g_signal_connect (button2, "clicked",
                  G_CALLBACK (callback), "program2");

gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box1), button2, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

gtk_widget_show(button2);

gtk_widget_show (box1);
/* Rest in gtk_main and wait for the fun to begin! */
gtk_main ();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you tried declaring GTKWidget buttons[2]; ?  And then use buttons[0] instead of button 1, and buttons[1] instead of button2?

Comment: @bruceg yes, I did this: `GtkWidget *button[2];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        button[i]=gtk_button_new();
    }
`and then used `button[0] ` and `button[1]` and it didnt work:(

Comment: @Anastasia; this should work, though; `GtkWidget *button[2];` clearly is an array of `GtkWidget*`, which is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use:

```
GtkWidget*  button[NB_BUTTONS];
```

then

```
int i;
for (i = 0: i < NB_BUTTONS; i++)
{
    char lab[16];
    char prg[16];
    sprintf(lab, "Run program%d", i);
    sprintf(prg, "program%d", i);
    button[i] = gtk_button_new_with_label (lab);
    g_signal_connect (button[i], "clicked",
              G_CALLBACK (callback), prg);
}
```

you can also define your label & prgram names this way:

```
char* label[] = {"Run program1", "Run whatever2" /*, ...*/ };
char* progs[] = {"program1", "whatever2" /*, ...*/ };
int i;
for (i = 0: i < NB_BUTTONS; i++)
{
    button[i] = gtk_button_new_with_label (label[i]);
    g_signal_connect (button[i], "clicked",
              G_CALLBACK (callback), progs[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to use for loop for creating buttons:(

Comment: Then you need some other, *parallel* arrays with parameter values. Or maybe an array of `struct` objects.

Comment: @shrike when you do this `sprintf(lab, "Run program%d", i);` this will pass Run program1 to button1, and Run program2 to button2? what if I have different names for buttons as a labels, for example Run script, and for another button Run shell, how do I implement that?

Comment: @Anastasia: see my edits

Comment: @shrike that makes a lot of sense, thank you very much:)

Comment: @shrike after implementing your code, I am getting an error: `excess elements in char array initializer near initialization for 'label' and for 'progs' ` any thoughts?

Comment: I tired everything, nothing helps:(

Comment: @Anastasia: sorry, my mistake... I fixed an error in the definitions of label and progs, see last edit (notice `char*` instead of `char` in definitions).